# How to get caret position in React?

Tags: reactjs, user-input

I have a bunch of inputs.

I want to get the position of caret so that if user will press a left arrow at the start of one input element it will take it to the end of the previous input element and same for right arrow but to next input.

So far, I can't find a way to get the position of caret so that I can take appropriate actions.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is provided id to the input field. There is a property `selectionEnd` in the input element.

`document.getElementById('inputElementId').selectionEnd`

or you could use a ref on the input element to get the `selectionEnd` too.

You can use this to get the cursor position. And you can handle the logic to move to the other input field in a handler

Comment: I tried selectionEnd but it is logging only zeroes even when I try different locations of caret.

Comment: which approach are you using? The one with ref or the one with `getElementById`?

Comment: I am using the ref one because it is the preferred way in react

Comment: can you post the way you are doing it. so that its easier for us to debug your implementation

Comment: I created a gist for my component hope this helps. https://gist.github.com/angelo1104/328a81cb0ca9327ce38efd083288df8f